# How to set 100 % height without having a vertical scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Context**

I have a navbar with a fixed height. I want the space underneath to fill the rest of the screen vertically. I also need to have a fixed height because I have a container inside the page that has a list that is scrollable but without scrolling the whole page `overflow: hidden`

**The Problem**

When I set a height on all parent elements of `100%` I get a vertical scrollbar. I found some answers on SO about "margin collapse" but nothing that could solve my problem.
`100vh` also won't work without having a scrollbar.

Here is the css for setup the height (#__next is just a div where next.js renders the page):

```
html,
body,
#__next {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The navbar is just a fixed pixel height, and the space below has `height: 100%`

Here is a screenshot that shows the vertical scrollbar:

[image]

I can't find any problems on the chrome inspector.

**This is how it should look (design file):**

[image]

How to solve this? I need to have both containers from screen "SippetPanel" and "SnippetContent" to take the remaining height without adding a scrollbar. It should also work to have a inner scrollbar with overflow hidden (later on when there are many items in the list like from design file).

Comment: You issue are the **100%**. 100% of what? You can use `calc()` to solve your issue: `height: calc(100% - navbarpx)` [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Comment: That solves the scrollbar, but now I have a weird white bar on the bottom that doesn't even appear in the devtools: https://imgur.com/a/dWaGjWC

Comment: If it does not appear in the devtools it probably is the `body`. Recheck your calculations.

Comment: I have this now: `html,
body,
#__next {
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  width: 100%;
}` this gives me the white bar on bottom

Comment: Ok got you. I have to set  it on html only and then set the remaining to 100%. But now I have to also calculate the margins and paddings, but it's fine now. Perfect for me. Add it as answer and I will acceppt it. Thx man

Comment: What if you set `html, body { height: 100%; }` and only do the calculations on `#__next`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that percentual heights refer to the height of the parent.
You can use `calc()` to solve your issue:

```
#__next{
    height: calc(100% - navbarpx);
    ...
}
```

[calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

For the padding issue you can look into [border-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Comment: If I add the margins to the calculation I have a white box on the bottom again -.- 
`box-sizing: border-box;` changes nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: As far  as I know, margins are not implied in `border-box`. Just paddings and borders. Looks like the option you need never made it. You could use a good old classic wrapper for that or try `::before` `::after`.

Comment: Perfect! I switched margins to paddings and now it works.

Comment: Alright. Do not rush  your layout phase and make it properly. Else it will always bite you back later.

Comment: Yeah thx mate. That's why I asked on SO because I hate it when things won't look the way I want it to be and I need to apply some dirty hacks :D Thx so much again

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to use flex-box, it allows you to explicitly say(take all available height.

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.navbar {
  flex: 30px 0 0;
  /* 30px height and do not grow or shint */
  background: red;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* take all available space */
  background: blue;
}

.body, html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
<div class="navbar"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm interesting. I will try that too. Does it work with overflow: auto in the "content" div so the content inside is scrollable, without scrolling the whole page / adding a vertical scrollbar? Thx mate

Comment: I am not sure about overflow and flex together(have heard about some issues), but I am almost sure that it is rather possible

Answer (score 0):

I usually just try different vh values, that means 90vh, 95.5vh etc. so it all sits perfectly. You can try to meddle with body position: absolute etc., but that would push everything into the navbar, so then you would need to fix it with additional margin-top.

So the best solution I see is to try different vh values for the height and find the sweet spot. You will need to do the same for different phone types as well with media queries, but it shoudn't really be hard.